# Why are the in-app purchases not listed on the App's detail page in ITC after submission & self-rejection of the binary + IAPs?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

What I did:

1) Set app to "Ready to upload" before assigning all the IAPs.

--- problem: Not possible to assign IAPs for submission with app once it#s "Ready to upload". Also not possible to undo "Ready to upload".

2) Submitted binary, instantly self-rejected it so I can assign IAPs for submission.

3) Assigned the IAPs.

4) Set app to "Ready to upload", then submitted binary again. PHEW.

5) Noticed issue with app. self-rejected binary again.

--- remember, old problem: Must assign IAPs to app details page before submitting first version, right?

6) Tried to assign IAPs to app details page. This time, no option to assign IAPs for submission with app. But IAPs still exist in the "Manage IAPs" section of app. With "Waiting for Review" status.

7) Submitting fixed binary.

---

**Quesion:** Am I in trouble now that I cannot specifically assign IAPs for review with first version of app, or will Apple see that a bunch of IAPs have been already submitted "earlier" (with a different binary that I just had to self-reject)?

Apple says "must submit IAPs **at the same time** as binary". Now after I self-rejected mine I can't assign those IAPs anymore to that binary, while IAPs remained "waiting for review". Previously the app detail page (the one with description, metadata, etc) had a table with all linked IAPs for review. This table **disappeared**, and now it looks like the IAPs are ahead of my binary in the review queue. Will Apple be clever enough to realize they belong to this binary? Or must I re-reject *everything*?

---

According to [THIS](http://endlesshybrids.com/2012/08/30/notes-on-setting-up-in-app-purchase-on-ios-itunes-connect/) page, ITC looks at it on a per-version basis. The version never changed. Always 1.0.